How do I make the box become the whole width of the text and reveal text
I have just started learning HTML 2 days ago and have stumbled upon something I have no clue how to do. I have a piece of text which creates a box with a title and a tiny bit of text. When the mouse hovers over it, it grows 1.05 times. I would like to add a function which when I click on the box, it makes the box grow to almost the whole width of the window and reveals a text in the box. I would also like for it to shrink if I click on the box again or if I click on another box. How should I go about it?


.games {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  /* background-color:  rgba(0, 0, 47,0.3); */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.game-list {
  margin: 30px;
  ;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 275px;
  width: 325px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: rgba(255, 75, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 40px 0 rgba(45, 57, 231, 0.37);
  backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
}

.game-list:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
<div class="games">
  <div class="game-list">
    <img src="https://rideawavedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dnd-dice-level-up-birthday-card-1.jpg" style="width:140px; height: 140px;" />
    <h1 style=" color:#FFFFFF">Chapter 1: </h1>
    <p style=" color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 20px">Step-by-Step</p>
  </div>
</div>



And this code is the CSS functions
(Also, I would like to mention that I started learning CSS and HTML a couple of days ago so please dumb it down a bit so I can understand)
I tried looking up a bit how to do this but for most of it I didnt understand if it was what I was looking for or not. So I turn here so I can get a direct answer.

We don't write code for you, we help you with code that isn't working. I suggest you do more research and come back with what you have tried.

the functions you seek would require scripting which then also requires learning JavaScript. Given the fact that you just started with HTML and CSS, I would highly recommend focusing on learning HTML first, then adding in more and more CSS to get a solid foundation in both languages before moving on to JS. Also, take a focus on HTML semantics. As soon as you use external CSS you should no longer use inline style.

@Paulie_D I wasnt expecting the code to be done for me. I mostly wanted someone to explain to me what kind of functions/ where I could find those functions that can help me. The way Ive taught myself how to code HTML till now was working on a already programmed website. However that doesnt give me the possibility of knowing many functions and Idk where to look.

You can use for that javascript (with event listeners) but as you are still learning HTML and CSS you can also use css and the the powerfull :has property as follow. (I just used here width:100vw when clicked, you can style it as you want)


.games {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    /* background-color:  rgba(0, 0, 47,0.3); */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  
 
  .games:has(input:checked) .game-list{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
  }
  
  .game-list {
    margin: 30px;
    ;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 275px;
    width: 325px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: rgba(255, 75, 255, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 40px 0 rgba(45, 57, 231, 0.37);
    backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 4px);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18);
  }
  
  .game-list:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
    <div class="games">
        <label for="clicked_checkbox">
        <div class="game-list">
          <input type="checkbox" hidden id="clicked_checkbox">
          <img src="https://rideawavedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dnd-dice-level-up-birthday-card-1.jpg" style="width:140px; height: 140px;" />
          <h1 style=" color:#FFFFFF">Chapter 1: </h1>
          <p style=" color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 20px">Step-by-Step</p>
        </div>
        </label>
      </div>




you should not teach him an invalid hack at the moment. He is new to HTML and has to learn the basics first. All he will learn from this is to use hacks that might work but have an invalid markup (inline-elements are not allowed to contain block-level elements with the sole exception of anchors!). The only good advise we can give him at this point is to slow down and learn the basics correctly first.

@tacoshy That is not a reason not to show him methods that are widely used as a solution here as well. Moreover that does not prevent him from still learning.

Like I said he will learn things that are not allowed. At this point, he has not the experience to make a difference between it works and it is not allowed. Has no knowledge about the downsides of the solutions (Inacccessibility, lower SEO ratings...). There already plenty bad tutorials including w3school out there that going to teach him incorrect coding. He will have a hard time to get rid of bad habits.

@tacoshy, where do you recommend I learn then? Because frankly, the way I just kind of self taught myself in these last couple of days was to take a website and find out what each of the different functions and others do to try and figure out how the whole thing works. I dont really have an idea about where to find good tutorials/learning places

@Mehdi So the box does become bigger but I have several blocks like that one under the other in the program and the way you showed me makes them all become big when I click on one. Is there a way to prevent this? And if I want to "hide" text that appears when it becomes bigger, how should I go about it?

@Ryochi I personally would recommend FreeCodeCamp but to take everything with a grain of salt. The only real guide you can be 100% sure that everything is correct is using the MDN WebDocs which is an official documentation for HTML, CSS, and JS. They have also tutorials there but they are harder to get into at start.

@tacoshy thanks for that. Finally a good place to start

@Ryochi yes you can still do it. You just either need to reorganise your HTML or adding other css for the required classes ex .games:has(input:checked) .game-list .otherclass{} for example. Keep trying you will find out. Enjoy coding!
